# Adding google oauth to laravel webservice

Tags: android, laravel, api, web-services, oauth-2.0

i have an android app with laravel webservice for server side. i want to add register/login with google (oauth2) to android app. for now, users can register with sms and email-pass in android app using

> laravel/passport

in server side. i now how to add google oauth to laravel but i don't know how to add it to laravel so users be able to register/login with google account from android app. when a request came  from user (android) first it goes to

> public function redirectToProvider()

which redirects to google. from now what i must do? i must redirect to google or i must return a response with json to user that contains GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID and GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ? and what i should do next?